# How can I auto update a web page's JSON content by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I build a simple JSP page as a service that returns JSON across different times, and the page shows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        [{"UID":999999,"UrlDate":"2015-11-24","SleepQ":70,"SleepQ_Lab":"普通","AttLevel":43.2864439246683,"AttLevel_Lab":"普通","MemLevel":60,"MemLevel_Lab":"普通"}]
  
        <h1></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is get the json part's certain elements like "AttLevel", and auto update.
I tried Query - AJAX get() and post() Methods on w3schools

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("140.138.77.151:8080/personalAssementNEW/", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

But nothing shows up.
The url itself is reachable, so I'm confused. 
How can I get the page's content?

update: 
I add: response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); in JSP, 
and now a JS test page seems can get a response, 
but AJAX still cannot. Is there something wrong with the code in description?

Comment: You're URL is not accessible when doing a getJSON...

Comment: It throws an error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Comment: Add `http://` before your IP address.

Comment: HenryDev: I see, can JSP allows the content being passed? Or JS can bypass the issue?  And what tool do you use to get the error message? Thank you. 
Thum Choon Tat: I've tried it, still responds nothing.

Comment: I add: response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); in JSP, and now JS seems can get response, but AJAX still cannot. Is there something wrong with the code?